# Vapor cloud deploy failed: Sockets Error: Failed trying to connect to http://redis.eu.vapor.cloud:6379

Tags: swift, vapor, swift-package-manager

I setup Vapor project manually with swift package manager. I follow the documentation. 
It build and runs successfully in my local machine, both for debug and release build.

But it failed to deploy to vapor cloud:

```
....
....
env: development
db: none
replicas: 1
replica size: free
branch: development
build: clean
Creating deployment [Done]
Connecting to build logs ...
Waiting in Queue [Failed]
Error: Sockets Error: Failed trying to connect to http://redis.eu.vapor.cloud:6379

Identifier: Sockets.SocketsError.connectFailed

Here are some possible causes: 
- The hostname or port is not valid
```

Anyone knows what caused this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I open an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/issues/1465) and got this response:

> Hi, It's usually caused by either a firewall, or a proxy preventing connection to our Redis cluster, that is providing log feedback to the terminal.
>
> We have seen it a couple of times, and are working on allowing to see log output in the dashboard, for these kind of situations :)

Still cannot find the solution.